# Free alternative to Teamviewer with commercial use allowed

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

Due to the COVID-19 outbreak, I'm looking for a desktop solution so that employees can access their work PC from home via a laptop.

Team-viewer is the obvious choice for most people, but I don't want to have to spend money on lots of licenses.

Are there any free software alternatives to Team-viewer out there that are available for commercial use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are not many options... a normal maintained software needs an income source.

One option you can look into is [**Ultra VNC**](https://www.uvnc.com/). It's a very powerful and customizable tool proudly free even for commercial use. The downside is gonna be that it is way more complicated to set up and use and is not as aesthetically nice.

Another possible option to look into would be [**Chrome Remote Desktop**](https://remotedesktop.google.com/). I believe it is also free for commercial use, but is much more limited and less customizable.